Mixing burnt Sterno with isopropyl alcohol
I’ve been using 2 hour Sterno cans recently. Once, burned out, remnants that are not yet burned/blackened are left. I combined all leftovers into a separate can. It always lights but almost immediately self extinguishes. I assume it was due to the gel already being dried out. As water is obviously not an option, I added 75% rubbing alcohol to it. Online research claims mixing rubbing alcohol with the gel will cause unpredictable results. Claims mixture will generate more heat to the point you can’t control reaction. Therefore, I’m too anxious to actually introduce a flame to it. Is it safe to do so?
Note: Starting only with 2oz gel mixed with .5oz isopropyl rubbing alcohol.

Remains after burning something like that contain a bit too little alcohol for continued combustion. I don't see a point in mixing it with another alcohol.

Alcohol burns slowly and cleanly, without gel. Perhaps remnants in can can gel it... or not. What does that have to do with chemistry, in your question??

Th gel in Sterno acts as a wick controlling combustion. adding liquid alcohol will result in uncontrolled burning and a possible conflagration if spilled.
